# Installing 2012 r2 on a dell t620

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am installing windows 2012 r2 on a new dell t620 1TB and raid 10. I am installing using LLC and here is what I see. 
Drvie 0 Partition: 1 OEM (reserve)
Drive 0 Partition: 2: OS 2.0GB
Drive 0 unallocated space: 925.5GB

For best practices, shouldn't I delete the Drive 0 partition 2 and how much space should I re-create for the OS? Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do with the server? Also, why RAID 10?

Answer (score 0):

The space allocation depends on what you need to do with this server. WS 2012 R2 requires a minimum  of 32GB (as per Microsoft). And yes, you should manage the unallocated space, of course, based on what you need to do.

Comment: Is it best practices to have two partitions, c:\ and d:\. Some say yes and some say no. This server will host 5 virtual servers. My other servers have 2 partitions. thanks

Comment: @HughLancaster Yes, you can put the OS on one partition of at least 50GB and leave the rest on a second partition for what else you need.